# Insert Year in ntpdate Results

Tags: regex, timestamp, ntp

I keep track of time offsets for my machine and just realized that my logs do not show the YEAR the line was taken.  So the question is quite simple...

How do I get `2016`, or rather current year, to be inserted?  For example `ntpdate -v` produces:

```
23 Jul 12:24:09 ntpdate[10251]: ntpdate 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Fri Oct 23 16:44:06 UTC 2015 (1)
23 Jul 12:24:09 ntpdate[10251]: no servers can be used, exiting
```

I would like it to produce:

```
23 Jul 2016 12:24:09 ntpdate[10251]: ntpdate 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Fri Oct 23 16:44:06 UTC 2015 (1)
23 Jul 2016 12:24:09 ntpdate[10251]: no servers can be used, exiting
```

Extra bonus points if a solution is provided to scan through a long text document and make the appropriate replacements working backwards from current date, i.e. a tool to fix my existing [and lacking] log.

Comment: The first line shows the year, isn't it?

Comment: You'll understand that '2015' there is the date of the executable's build, called for by the `-v` option.

Comment: Oh, I see. sorry, missed that. I would suggest something like `ntpdate -v  2>&1 | awk -v year="$(date +%Y)" '{$3=year" "$3}1'` However, I'm not sure how stable that will at `Dec 31 23:59:59`. That's why I'm not adding it as an answer.

Comment: That works, thank you!  I would recommend you make an answer out of it since whatever issue comes up "at 23:59:59 on year change" is out of scope!

Comment: Nah. Imagine a creator of software to control nuclear power plants would pick that up? I don't want to be responsible for that. I'm glad to see that it helps you.

Comment: That software guy may actually be the guy working the atomic clock whose pull utility points to the right millisecond, but will not get the year.

Comment: let's see ...... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credit goes to hek2mgl.

Something like this works very well:

```
$ ntpdate -v 2>&1 | awk -v year="$(date +%Y)" '{$3=year" "$3}1'
```

Note that the year of the call to `date` is inserted, and could possibly not match the rest of the timestamp provided by `ntpdate` late on December 31st.